# Angular elementRef.nativeElement.offsetWidth's value does not match width of component in the browser

Tags: javascript, css, angular

From inside a component, I need to get the actual width of the component once the page completes loading. I think the value that I get is actually closer to the width of the entire window.

My component's markup:

```
<div>
The width of this component is {{ componentWidth }} px.
</div>
```

Its .ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-my-component',
   templateUrl: './app-my-component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./app-my-component.scss']
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
   private componentWidth: number;

   constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
   }

   ngOnInit() {
       this.componentWidth = this.elementRef.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
   }
}
```

The .scss file:

```
:host {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Now, this component is placed on a page's html markup, and that page's .ts file is default as created by `ng g component Home` where `Home` is the name of the page. Its .scss is empty. Here is home.html:

```
<div>
   home works!
   <app-my-component>
   </app-my-component>
</div>
```

Nothing too fancy there. However, I also need to show you my app.component.html:

```
<div>
  <nav>...</nav>
  <div class="router-outlet">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

And app.component.scss:

```
.router-outlet {
   padding: 10px;
 }
```

Now, when I run it, the output on the page turns out, in my case, 1420 px. However, when I inspect that component on Firefox, it says that the component is actually only 1403 px. If I inspect the entire document, it is 1423 px wide. I see that the 10px padding on either side of the component was applied, and I see that 20px difference between the entire document down to my component. I have several questions.

How did `elementRef.nativeElement.offsetWidth` turn out to be 1420px, which is closer to the full width of the viewport, 1423px?

Where did that 3px difference come from?

Should I be listening to specific events instead of obtaining the width value off `elementRef` in `ngOnInit()`?

In case you're wondering why I need to get the width value, I may need this one day for gaming, which I believe would need to know the exact width of the component.

Comment: Do this in ngAfterViewInit() I believe it will do the trick

Comment: It does get called, but console.log(this.elementRef.nativeElement.offsetWidth + " px at ngAfterViewInit()); still displays 1420px.

Comment: I have noticed such changes are caught with ngAfterViewChages. Have you tried that. It might help capture changes. Remember, view changes are also triggered when the view is being created.

Comment: Have you put body and html padding:0 ?

Comment: @Gary - I think you meant ngAfterViewChecked, and it finally will give me the value I want, but then I can't set new values to my component's variables based on the new value of elementRef.nativeElement.offsetWidth, though - I'll get an error.

Comment: Yes I meant `ngAfterViewChecked`. It gives you the changes for views. Thank you for rectifying it. I remember somewhere in angular.io site which said to avoid to use `nativeElement.xxx` to apply styles. But try `nativeElement.styles.offsetWidth` and if it works. Second, you should typically use the `Renderer2` method in angular for any dom changes - preferably